# Element getting added to LinkedList even though the variable is not being called

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist

I have an instance variable

```
Queue<ArrayList<String>> path = new LinkedList<>();
```

and in a method I have this

```
ArrayList<String> shortestPath = new ArrayList<String>();
HashSet<String> visited = new HashSet<String>();
Queue<String> q = new LinkedList<String>();
ArrayList<String> tempArrNew = null;
...
while{
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tempArr = new ArrayList<>();
for(ArrayList<String> a : path){
    tempArr.add(a);
}
for{
q.add(o);
visited.add(o);
tempArrNew = tempArr.get(tempArr.size()-sub);
tempArrNew.add(o);
path.add(tempArrNew);
}
}
```

The thing is, it is adding to the *path* variable in the line "tempArrNew.add(o)", o being a String. So for example, the second for loop is doing this...

path = [[banana]]
...
o = apple
apple gets added to q fine
apple gets added to visited fine
tempArrNew  = [banana] works fine
but then when I go to add apple to tempArrNew, it adds it to tempArrNew (making it [banana, apple]) fine but for some reason it is also adding it to the arrayList in path, even though I don't even call it in that line, making path = [[banana, apple]]. So then when I add tempArrNew to path, path becomes [[banana, apple],[banana, apple]], when I want it to be [[banana], [banana, apple]].

I have no idea what's going on so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `tempArrNew = tempArr.get(tempArr.size()-sub);` is **not** a *copy* operation. `tempArrNew.add(o);` adds `o` to the same `List` (as you observed).

Comment: Ahhhh thank you so much, I didn't know that.